# How to use more then one value using map

Tags: react-native, dictionary

What's up guys! I have those 3 const `Names`, `Imgs`, and `Msgs` **I need to do something to the `name, img, msg` works**. Only the `Names` is working, so I just can use the `name`  I tried uses `Object.values(Names, Imgs, Msgs).map((name, img, msg) => {...` but again only the `Names` works

```
//Home.js
forNames() {
    const { informations } = this.props;
    const Names = informations.names;
    const Imgs = informations.photos;
    const Msgs = informations.messages;


    const InformationsAll = Object.values(Names).map((name, img, msg) => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.peopleCont}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image style={styles.imgs} source={img} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.contact}> 
            <Text key={name} style={styles.name}> {name} </Text>
            <View style={styles.msgContainer}>
              <Icon name="check-double" size={12} style={styles.icon} />
              <Text style={styles.text}> {msg} </Text> 
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    })
    return InformationsAll;
}
```

Those consts are from here.

```
//App.js
const info = {
  names: {
    name1: 'Mike',
    name2: 'Maggie',
    name3: 'Omar',
    name4: 'Sophie',
    name5: 'Lilly',
    name5: 'Manuella',
    name6: 'Luke',
    name7: 'William',
    name8: 'Lian',
    name9: 'Michael'
  },

  messages: {
    msg1: 'Ok!',
    msg2: 'Where ?',
    msg3: 'CSGO today ?',
    msg4: 'At Central Park ok ?',
    msg5: 'Lol',
    msg6: 'My dog is asking the link',
    msg7: 'Wtf hahah',
    msg8: 'See you tomorrow',
    msg9: 'Above is her number'
  },

  photos: {
    img1: Man3,
    img2: Teen3,
    img3: Woman2,
    img4: Woman3,
    img5: Man1,
    img6: Man2,
    img7: Teen1,
    img8: Teen2,
    img9: Woman4
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your info object is totally wrong way. Why are you doing like that ?

**Good way**

```
const info = [
    {
      name: 'Mike',
      msg: 'Ok!',
      img: Man3
    },
    {
      name: 'Maggie',
      msg: 'Where ?',
      img: Teen3
    },
    ...
]
```

And

```
const InformationsAll = this.props.informations.map((info) => {
    return (
        <View key={info.name} style={styles.peopleCont}>
            <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image style={styles.imgs} source={info.img} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.contact}> 
            <Text style={styles.name}> {info.name} </Text>
            <View style={styles.msgContainer}>
                <Icon name="check-double" size={12} style={styles.icon} />
                <Text style={styles.text}> {info.msg} </Text> 
            </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
})
return InformationsAll;
```